# How to include a support file for rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm building a rails 4 app. I created a support file to simulate a login. Here are the files

#### spec/support/spec_test_helper.rb

```
module SpecTestHelper
  def login(user)
    request.session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def current_user
    User.find(request.session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

#### spec_helper.rb

```
config.include SpecTestHelper, :type => :controller
```

#### controller spec

```
describe BooksController, "user role" do

  user = Fabricate(:user) do
    role { Role.find_by_account_type("user") }
  end

  login(user)
end
```

The support file gives an undefined method error. This is part of the error message:

```
spec/controllers/books_controller_spec.rb:27:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `login' for #<Class:0x007f9f83193438> (NoMethodError)
```

I'm testing CanCan. I know the correct way to test CanCan is testing the Ability but that's already done.

Comment: Please include the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `login(user)` call within a `before` or an `it` block, instead of directly within the `describe`:

```
let(:user) do
  Fabricate(:user) do
    role { Role.find_by_account_type("user") }
  end
end

before do
  login(user)
end
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much that was the problem.

Answer (score 33):

I added this line in `spec_helper.rb` and it works in 3rd Rails

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

Maybe another (more pretty) solution exists

Comment: so pay attention on @Ash's answer - you really should build records and call methods inside it/before/let...

Answer (score 16):

There can be two files under rspec dir: `rails_helper.rb` and `spec_helper.rb`. If you want to provide support for rails-dependent classes, you should use `rails_helper` to tell rails to load the modules under the `'spec/support'` dir.

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

To declare the shared module, you want to use it inside the config block.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.include <YourModuleName>::<YourClassName>, :type => :controller
  ...
end
```

But, if your class doesn't require rails at all, you can load it under `spec_helper`, which will not load rails to run the tests.
Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24145760/1804846) and to [this reference](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade#default-helper-files) to learn more about it.

Answer (score 7):

Alternative to the answer provided by @gotva.  It's slightly more verbose, but will work in both Rails 3 and 4:

```
Dir[File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'support','**','*.rb'))].each {|f| require f}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your spec only add such class or module like following

> both files in the path: spec/

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "rails_helper"

class SharedHelper   
  def defined_action
    ...
  end
end

# frozen_string_literal: true

require "rails_helper"
require_relative "shared_helper"

RSpec.describe "Test request", type: :request do
  before(:all) do
    SharedHelper.new.defined_action
  end
end
```