# RSpec doesn't load my class even though it loads in the Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I've got a class inside `app/models/parser` called `data.rb` with contents :

```
class Parser::Data 
  def method1
  end
end
```

Nothing fancy at this point. I'm trying to write a test for it before implementing too much, just did default RSpec install for Rails.

My RSpec file is in `spec/models/parser/data_spec.rb` and is very basic so far:

```
require 'spec_helper.rb'

describe Parser::Data do
  let(:parser) { Parser::Data.new }
end
```

When I run the test I get this error:

```
spec/models/parser/data_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Parser (NameError)
```

I tried placing `module Parser` around the `Data` class in the same directory `app/models/parser`, also I've tried moving it to `lib/parser` doing the same module wrapping class, and added `lib/parser` to autoload in the `application.rb` but nothing has worked so far.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Putting it in a `module Parser` should have worked. Unless, there is a model `Parser`. In which case, put it in a `class Parser`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require 'rails_helper'` instead of `spec_helper`. Requiring only `spec_helper` reproduces the issue for me, and requiring `rails_helper` fixes it. More on `spec_helper` vs. `rails_helper` (including performance implications) here: [How is spec/rails_helper.rb different from spec/spec_helper.rb? Do I need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145329/how-is-spec-rails-helper-rb-different-from-spec-spec-helper-rb-do-i-need-it/24145760)

I reproduced the problem by running RSpec with `bundle exec rspec`. If I run RSpec with `bin/rspec` (that's a binstub generated by the spring-commands-rspec gem) it doesn't care which helper file I require. I guess spring loads more eagerly.

Comment: Requiring `rails_helper` causes the entire rails environment to load (which in turn enables rails constant auto-loading, fixing the issue).  If your class does not depend on rails, I recommend _not_ requiring `rails_helper` -- if you require it, the boot time to run your spec file goes way up.  Instead, I recommend you just add a simple `require` to the top of the spec file to load the `parser/data.rb` file.

Comment: @MyronMarston I'd vote for that if you wrote it as an answer. Not an issue if one is using spring, though. Updating ...