# Rspec can't find ActiveAdmin controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, activeadmin

I'm trying to test a custom member action in ActiveAdmin using rspec.

**app/admin/inactive_user.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register InactiveUser do
  member_action :activate, method: :put do
    user = User.new(email: resource.email, password: generate_activation_code)
    resource.destroy if user.save
    send_activation_email user
    redirect_to admin_inactive_users_path, notice: "#{user.email} was activated"
  end
end
```

**app/spec/admin/inactive_user_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Admin::InactiveUserController do
  render_views

  before do
    @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin, confirmed_at: Date.yesterday)
    authenticate_user @admin
  end

  describe "PUT #activate" do
    before(:each) do
      @inactive_user = FactoryGirl.create(:inactive_user)
      put :activate, id: @inactive_user.id
    end

    it "should redirect to inactive users index" do
      expect(response).to redirect_to(admin_inactive_users_path)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
NameError:
  uninitialized constant Admin
# ./spec/admin/inactive_user_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

I have tried [this](http://blog.robotex.de/read/rails-active-admin-rspec-fixing-uninitialized-constant-admindashboardcontroller-with) without any luck.

Plus, if you know of any project that uses rspec to do tests on this kind of things it would be great, the doc doesn't say much.

**Update:**
Right now it's running the `active_admin` initializer after the test:
An error occurred while loading

```
NameError:
  uninitialized constant Admin
# ./spec/admin/inactive_user_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'

[3, 12] in /Users/lucia/Documents/frogs-api-remote/config/initializers/active_admin.rb
    3:   # == Site Title
    4:   #
    5:   # Set the title that is displayed on the main layout
    6:   # for each of the active admin pages.
    7:   #
=>  8:   config.site_title = "Frogs App"
    9:
   10:   # Set the link url for the title. For example, to take
   11:   # users to your main site. Defaults to no link.
   12:   #
```

Comment: This assumes you have `config.default_namespace = :admin` in `initializers/active_admin.rb`  Is the initializer being skipped?

Comment: @PiersC added that line to the config but it still fails, how can I check if the initializer is being skipped?

Comment: puts debug statements? pry?

Comment: @PiersC it runs the initializer after the test fails, I will update the question with that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try requiring `rails_helper` instead of `spec_helper`, see [How is spec/rails_helper.rb different from spec/spec_helper.rb? Do I need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145329/how-is-spec-rails-helper-rb-different-from-spec-spec-helper-rb-do-i-need-it)

`rails_helper` should require `File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)` then `config/environment` should call `Rails.application.initialize!` and that should be loading `initalizers/active_admin.rb` and defining `Admin::InactiveUserController` before your test starts.

After `initializers/active_admin` has run you should be able to inspect `ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces.map(&:name)`, which in your case should be `[:admin]`. If so then inspect `ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:admin].resources.map(&:c‌​ontroller)` which should give you the list of controllers that have been created.

Comment: You're right, by requiring `rails_helper` I get `initalizers/active_admin.rb` to load before the test but I keep getting the same error

Comment: After initializers/active_admin has run you should be able to inspect `ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces.map(&:name)`, which in your case should be `[:admin]`.  If so then inspect `ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:admin].resources.map(&:controller)` which should give you the list of controllers that have been created. Do you have any other tests you can compare to?

Comment: I used this `ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:admin].resources.map(&:c‌​ontroller)` and realized it was `Admin::InactiveUsersController`, so I was missing an 's'. Thanks!

Comment: Congrats.  I'm guessing you're not first or last to get stuck on this.  Please consider renaming the question to "Rspec can't find ActiveAdmin controller"