# Rails RSpec get :index railses undefined method get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a WelcomeController#index which simply renders index.html.erb. I need to test this by checking whether a link in the page has a particular href as passing some specific query parameter can change this href.

I want to test the basic index page without query parameter.

In spec/controllers/welcome_controller_spec.rb I have,

```
require 'spec_helper'

# describe WelcomeController, :type => :controller do
#     it "tests index page content" do
#         get :index
#         assert_response 200
#     end
# end

RSpec.describe WelcomeController, :type => :controller do
    it "should go to the index page" do
        get 'index'
        response.should render_template "welcom/index"
        response.body.should =~ /test link text/
    end
end
```

But when I run `rspec spec/controllers/welcome_controller_spec.rb` I keep getting this error

```
Failures:

  1) WelcomeController should go to the index page
     Failure/Error: get 'index'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::WelcomeController:0x0000000003ac3ca0>
       Did you mean?  gets
                      gem
     # ./spec/controllers/welcome_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00038 seconds (files took 1.09 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/welcome_controller_spec.rb:12 # WelcomeController should go to the index page
```

I using Ruby 2.5, Rails 5 and RSpec 3

Comment: try to change `require 'spec_helper'` to `require 'rails_helper'`.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145329/how-is-spec-rails-helper-rb-different-from-spec-spec-helper-rb-do-i-need-it

Comment: Try putting a ‘/‘ in front of the word ‘index’ in your get call.

Comment: Made the changes and it now gives the following error,

/home/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@rails5/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.2/lib/rspec/rails/fixture_support.rb:25:in `block in <module:FixtureSupport>': undefined method `use_transactional_fixtures=' for #<Class:0x0000000003c926a8> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  use_transactional_tests=
               use_transactional_tests
               use_transactional_tests?

Answer (score 0):

`type: :controller` should be passed as an option to `describe` method:

```
Rspec.describe WelcomeController, type: :controller do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake but still, it is giving the same error